# Bad merchant id passed payzapp ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using Payzapp (HDFC) payment gateway, but i am getting "bad merchant id passed" in response. It would be really great if any one can tell me exact solution.

PAYMENT REPONSE: {

```
merchantInfo = "<null>";

msgHash = "<null>";

registeredUas = "<null>";

resCode = 050;

resDesc = "Bad Merchant Id passed!";

specialMer = 0;

transactionInfo = "<null>";

webToken = "<null>";

webUrl = "<null>";

wibmoCustomer = 0;

wibmoTxnId = "<null>";

wibmoTxnToken = "<null>";
```

}

Comment: The merchant ID you are passing to them is not correct. Hard to see what answer you expect based on the (no) information you have provided.

Comment: WSMerchantInfo *aMerchantInfo = [[WSMerchantInfo alloc] init];
aMerchantInfo.merchantCountryCode = @"IN";
aMerchantInfo.merchantName = @"App Name";

// PRODUCTION
//    aMerchantInfo.merchantID = @"534411755**********";
//    aMerchantInfo.merchantAppID = @"7***";

Comment: WSTransactionInfo *aTransactionInfo = [[WSTransactionInfo alloc] init];
aTransactionInfo.transactionCurrency = @"356";
aTransactionInfo.transactionAmount = @"100";
aTransactionInfo.merchantAppData = @"AppDATA";
aTransactionInfo.transactionDescription = @"Transaction from sample merchant for amount 1";
aTransactionInfo.supportedPaymentType = @[@"w.ds.pt.card_visa", @"w.ds.pt.card_mastercard"];
aTransactionInfo.messageHash = self.messageHash;
aTransactionInfo.merchantTransactionId = self.merchantTransactionID;

Comment: WSCustomerInfo *aCustomerInfo = [[WSCustomerInfo alloc] init];
aCustomerInfo.customerEmail = @"someone@enstage.com";
aCustomerInfo.customerMobile = @"112233****";
aCustomerInfo.customerName = @"kunal gupta";
aCustomerInfo.customerDateOfBirth = @"20010101";

Comment: WibmoSDK *aWibmoSDK = [[WibmoSDK alloc] init];
[self.navigationController presentViewController:aWibmoSDK animated:YES completion:^{
    [aWibmoSDK setTransactionInfo:aTransactionInfo];
    [aWibmoSDK setMerchantInfo:aMerchantInfo];
    [aWibmoSDK setCustomerInfo:aCustomerInfo];
    [aWibmoSDK setDelegate:self];

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The tags you were using are not appropritate for this question. Please review [What are tags, and how should I use them?](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) Also, please use the edit button to edit your question rather than adding unreadable comments.